# Sub template (or sub section) in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Can't I extend a layout which already extends another one?

I wanted to have

```
// layouts/default.blade.php
<html>
...
@yield('content')
...
</html>
```

and until then its fine...

```
// users/myaccount.blade.php
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
    @section('user-page')
        some default static content for the user page
    @stop
@stop
```

but when I try to modify the content of the `user-page` section with

```
// users/orders.blade.php
@extends('users.myaccount')

@section('user-page')
    content for messages page
@stop
```

No deal. It renders the content for my account, but not the content for orders.
I am calling it from the UserController like this

```
public function orders() {
    return View::make('users.orders');
}
```

What am I missing? Can I extend a layout only once?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this ?

***`layouts/default.blade.php`***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>
    @include('users.myaccount')
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

***`users/myaccount.blade.php`***

```
<p>some default static content for the user page</p>
```

***`users/orders.blade.php`***

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
    <p>content for messages page</p>
@stop
```

***And the controller function,***

```
public function orders() {
    return View::make('users.orders');
}
```